# How to limit user access to Custom Post Type in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website with a Custom Post Type called 'Events'. 
 I need users to be allowed to visit one Event page **only after a registration form**. This form has to show up **every time a user try to access a new Event**, so every registration form works only for that specific Event page, not for other ones (a new form will be required to access other Events). 
 How would you solve this issue?

Comment: We solve it by developing a plugin... or using some of these ready made solutions : https://brytdesigns.com/best-wordpress-event-registration-plugins-2020/

Comment: I tried Tickera plugin, issue is that Event will reside on my website, it's something virtual, so that particualr Event page has to be restricted. There's no need of tickets, I should restrict users access to Event they haven't filled a required form